# Twitter bootstrap 3 modal open on page load without effect

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a authentication page which use the modal to display the form.

If login/password are correct, users got redirected to a SPA.

If they are not correct, I'll need to show the **exact** same page with the login form open and an error message.

Is there a way to show a view with the twitter bootstrap already open, **no effect/delay**.
I also need to have the data-dismiss button act like he is supposed to.

Here is a `jsfiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/267/

```
// no black overlay, dismiss not binded
```

Comment: Post a jsfiddle, adding bold text does not help

Comment: Jordan, bold is for people who answer to get point, not to help. Look down, most haven't read all my question before answering, and you want a fiddle of what ? a header including bootstrap and modal code from bootstrap ? really I think you won't help

Comment: It is common courtesy in SO to provide a jsfiddle when you can. This helps users answer your question because they can test it instead of guess. You will find many more people answering your question when you have a fiddle to work on. You do not have to follow this suggestion but I highly recommend it.

Comment: Ok @JordanD, I added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal({
      //options for modal

    })
});
```

This will open your modal on document ready. Check out any additional options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

To remove the fade effect you have to remove it from the modal wrapper class:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="modal bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Thanks but modal('show') trigger the modal display event, which include fade/drop effects.

Comment: @Dimitri remove the fade from wrapper class. Edited my answer

Comment: Still, I lose the data-dismiss event and overlay

Comment: @Dimitri post a jsfiddle in your question and I will look at it.

Comment: Sorry I won't, you have 1337 réputation, I don't want change that. But trust me, you don't need a js fiddle for something i don't know how to do, just use the framework and copy some html markup, you'll see it's not that obvious

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle where it automatically opens - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqT3d/2/)

Pulled that right from the Bootstrap site - [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thanks but modal('show') trigger the modal display event, which include fade/drop effects.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure HTML approach:

1. The wrapper for the modal has a class `fade`. This class is what provides the animation, so not adding the class will cause the modal to just appear.
2. You can then add `data-show="true"` so that the modal opens when it is initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried, but doing this make me lose the data-dismiss button event, and the black overlay also. View result is different of the page user was when he tried to login.